# Find the biggest square constructed from a single number

Tags: algorithm

Given a 2D matrix that consists of numbers 0-9, how do I find the largest square that is constructed from a single number?

For example,

```
12039487067
81111012389
01111111769
71181231987
11111891167
86171231222
17130471282
37111111222
47061902547
```

There are 3 squares:

1. starts at (1, 1) and ends at (4, 4)
2. starts at (2, 2) and ends at (7, 7)
3. starts at (5, 8) and ends at (7, 10)

The biggest square is the second one. And how do I do it if I have to find a rectangle?

I know the logic for finding solid square, but not when its hollow. Any ideas?

Comment: How are these numbers related to the squares?

Comment: This question is more of a discussion, so it will probably be closed. But have you considered searching along the diagonal, starting from every occurrence of 1?

Comment: @folkol I think the op meant the square can be formed from any number, not just 1s.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Just repeat for every digit.

Comment: The square need not be aligned along the diagonal, like square 3 for example.

Comment: I meant the diagonal starting with the current number. Like "For every 1 in the matrix, search diagonally for 1's, and form a square with the one furthest away".

Comment: But how do I know that a 1 that I hit is a part of the square?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like: For every position in the array call a recursive subrutine that matches (X'+1, Y'') and (X'',Y'+1) with the first value. If some of those dont match start recursion with (X', Y''+1) and (X''+1,Y') until they meet again on the same spot where you can say you've got an square…

without backtracking that would also deal with the "weird" case in your example of (2,2)->(4,4)

Answer (score 0):

It may help to first scan the matrix to compute auxiliary matrices left,up that measure the number of consecutive entries in each direction.

So, for example, left[2,5] would be equal to 3 because there are 3 consecutive elements to the left of element 2,5 with the same value.

For a matrix of size n*n these matrices can be computed in O(n^2) using straightforward dynamic programming.

Once you have these matrices you can check in O(1) time whether any particular candidate rectangle is valid by checking the corners.

This then gives an immediate O(n^3) algorithm for finding the best square (simply test each of the O(n^3) possible square locations), an an O(n^4) method for rectangles.

You can also get an O(n^3) method for finding the best rectangle
 by fixing the top and bottom coordinates of the rectangle (O(n^2) choices) and then iterating across the matrix.  You then need to consider at each x coordinate the following cases:

1. Can we continue the previous rectangle (possible if the colour at the top and bottom matches the current colour)
2. Can we complete the previous rectangle (possible if there is a connection from top to bottom with the current colour)
3. Otherwise, can we start a new rectangle (possible if there is a connection from top to bottom with a new colour)

All of these take O(1) by using the top matrix, and there are O(n) x coordinates, so altogether this takes O(n^3) to find the best rectangle outline.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple solution for finding max square.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include<cstring>
#include <math.h>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
#include <queue>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

bool flag = false;
char ch[100][100];

int findMxSq(int leftX, int upY, int rightX, int downY){
    int mx = (rightX-leftX+1)*(downY-upY+1);
    bool flag = true;
    char c = ch[leftX][upY];
    for(int i=leftX; i<=rightX; i++){
        flag &= (c==ch[i][downY+1]);
    }
    if(flag) mx = max(mx, findMxSq(leftX,upY,rightX,downY+1));
    flag = true;
    for(int i=upY; i<=downY; i++){
        flag &= (c==ch[rightX+1][i]);
    }
    if(flag) mx = max(mx, findMxSq(leftX,upY,rightX+1,downY));
    return mx;
}
int main(){
    memset(ch,'*',sizeof(ch));
    for(int i=1; i<=9; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<=11; j++)
            cin>>ch[i][j];
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=9; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<=11; j++)
            ans = max(ans,findMxSq(i,j,i,j));
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```